# How to Set Last Row Data Paging

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, data-paging

I have trouble to set last row for paging.

[I set Page size: 10 in gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UT39Y.jpg)

This my behind code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindData();
    }

    public void BindData()
    {
        string strConnection = @"Data Source=.\sa;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ProductId, ProductName, SupplierId from Products", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();  

    }

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindData();  
    }
```

The Result:

[The page 7 have 10 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWlmL.jpg)

[but after I change page 7 to last page have only less than 10 rows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKBTM.jpg)

[I want the last page have 10 rows although data table 7 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K30kc.jpg)

anybody can improve my code.

Comment: You can use Query to check the table child element and whenever it has less than then row you can append additional rows to it.... if you want to..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Empty row in the Dataset.table (No of a row to add it depends on how many rows less than the page size)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindData();
    }

public void BindData()
{
    string strConnection = @"Data Source=.\sa;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ProductId, ProductName, SupplierId from Products", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    int rowcount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    int remainingCount = 10 - (rowcount % 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < remainingCount; i++)
    {
        DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();  

}

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindData();  
}
```

Comment: @Roberts Glad to help you